# php finding results when plus sign involved

Tags: php

I have a line of code that scans a dataset:

dataset:

```
+117251093918
+1174418217128
0112347063455555
```

php line of code:

```
 if (substr($row['someData'],0,3) == "011")
 {
    //do stuff
 }

+117251093918
+1174418217128
0112347063455555
```

I would expect to find 1 result in this dataset, however all 3 results are found according to php.  any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `===`. The operator `==` casts between two different types if they are different, while the `===` operator performs a 'typesafe comparison'. That means that it will only return true if both operands have the same type and the same value.

In the example below, the first for loop shows why it returns `good`.  The `===` exhibits typesafe comparison, it means unless the two values are of the same type and equal, it will return `false`. Whereas, `==` returns true regardless of the types, it just has to be equal.

```
<?php

// assume your row['somedata'] is this
$r = +11;

 //returns good
 if ((substr($r,0,3)) == "+11")
 {
    echo "Good";
 }

 //doesn't return any
 if ((substr($r,0,3)) === "+11")
 {
    echo "Good One";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: You did notice my answer, right? By the way, what you are saying is not correct, even if both operands are strings / the same, type casting can still take place. Like here.

Comment: I only noticed your answer when I finished writing mine. So no, I didn't copy your answer if that's what you are saying. Moreover, which part are you referring to, == or ===?

Comment: When you use `==` type-casting can take place even when both operands are of the same type (strings in this case).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure you compare strings on both sides, use a triple `=`:

```
 if (substr($row['someData'],0,3) === "011")
```

That way php will not convert any variable types to make the comparison work; both content and variable type now have to be equal.

In your case both sides are converted to integers, see the [following example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0BWB3Y):

```
 var_dump("+11" == "011");
```

returns `true`

and [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1g7BTc):

```
var_dump("+11" === "011");
```

returns `false`.

Check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more details.